# Please help me with an event with confirmation and list of people attending

Tags: drupal-7

I'm using Drupal 7 for building a website for a non-profit organisation. I'm fairly unexperienced but I managed to impliment most of the requitements.

However, I need help with the following:
I need a to have a content type with a form attached to it. The type is an event where people can confirm whether they will attend or not. The list of people attending should be displayed on the event page.

It's the last part that I'm trying already for several day's without success. I can't figure out a way to display the list of people attendig the event on the event's page.

Can you explain me how you would make an event with confirmation and displaying the list of people attending?
Thanks,
Marc

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight disconnect in your question - if you are using webform to attach the info you will find this much harder because it's not associated with the node itself. If you add the form elements as CCk fields this is easy BUT some people will feel uncomfortable using content types like this and you need to be very careful with permissions - allowing anon to post into a content type is asking for trouble. Maybe there is a module to turn webform info into proper nodes somewhere?!

Assuming CCK method though:

The easy way is to make a view that lists the attendents name on your content type (people_attending) and filters on the 'coming' field = yes. This assumes you are not reinventing the wheel and you have set a CCK field on your content type as a yes/on 'Are you attending?' select.

The difficult bit depends on what is on your existing events page! The quick way would be to leave the main area of your events pages as is and then make your view into a block, then tell the block to just appear on that page.

So something like this:

```
Page:                    Block (view filtered on 'attending' and showing name)
EVENT STUFF              Name
                         Name
```

Comment: I know this is really picky but there is no CCK in Drupal 7, it's just referred to as the field API...just to avoid any confusion :)

Comment: Thanks Allan... I understand that (CCK)fields are a better option than webforms. I'll give the fields a try, but does it require (complex) PHP coding tom make the form?